Continuation of Correct Formula Approach
See: Correct Formula Approach
This is a continuation of that question.  I have implemented the LOOKUP function Described there, and now have a separate column printing dates minus 2 weeks where needed.  In a new column I have added the Following IF statement:
IF(WEEKDAY([@[Two Week Warning]],3)=4,"Yes", "Not a Friday") - Note that I've re-ordered the Weekdays so that Monday is now 0, using setting 3.
The above formula works great on the rows where column Two Week Warning has a Date, but I would like to apply the formula to the entire column, so that Yes or Not a Friday will automatically populate in the New Column. The issue here is: I can't test if Two Week Warning is Empty on the new column because Two Week Warning contains the LOOKUP formula and is never Blank.  When I apply the formula to the entire column, I get the #VALUE! error because not all the Cells in the Two Week Warning column contain a date.
How cab I apply the above Formula using AND or OR based on a Formula Result that produces "" for an "empty" cell?

I think it may be best if you can share your date in a live sheet so we can see exactly what you have where. You can easily generate an anonymous sheet to share using the Blank Sheet Maker

It would be useful if you showed what you have and what you want to have.
But instead of testing the ISBLANK condition, you can test = "". Then blank cells and those with empty text will be included.

@MGonet The previous post which I did link has the example plus a screenshot of the Answer'ers verified test.  I don't know why I would need to recreate it, when all I did was add the formula from that answer back into the same sample format as a new column

@eyounh100 Because a question needs to be a step up to a solution to future visitors with similar problems. If you'd seek Google to get a solution to this question and ending up here. Would you dive in deeper, or seek for a different hit from Google (or Superuser itself even)?

=IF([@[Two Week Warning]]="","",IF(WEEKDAY([@[Two Week Warning]],3)=4,"yes","Not a Friday"))

FYI: You can just replace the TRUE and FALSE arguments of the IF statement with another IF (or any other formula).

This just Shows how rusty I am at Excel.  That FYI really helped...
